# Take first and last point from mouse drag in xna/monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have a grid of tiles, and I want to be able to grab an area like so: [image]

Here is my current code:

```
case clickState.select:

    if (IsActive && //Check if window is active and mouse is within working area
        Mouse.GetState().X > 0 &&
        Mouse.GetState().X < windowSize.X - 32 &&
        Mouse.GetState().Y > 0 &&
        Mouse.GetState().Y < windowSize.Y - 32)
    {
        if (Mouse.GetState().LeftButton != ButtonState.Pressed && prevMouseState)//if has released, and last frame it wasnt:
        {
            Vector2 Topos = toTilePos(new Vector2(Mouse.GetState().X, Mouse.GetState().Y)); //convert the onscreen postion to coordinates on the grid
            selected.Z = Topos.X;  //yes i am using a vector4 to store 2 vector2s
            selected.W = Topos.Y;  //Z =x2, W = y2
            break;
        }
        if (Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && !prevMouseState) //If started to click:
        {
            if (selected != new Vector4(0)) selected = new Vector4(0);  //Reset selected area
            prevMouseState = true; //The previouse state will be updated
            Vector2 Topos = toTilePos(new Vector2(Mouse.GetState().X, Mouse.GetState().Y)); //convert to tile space
            selected.X = Topos.X; // set
            selected.Y = Topos.Y; // set
            break;
       }
   }
   else if (prevMouseState == true)
       prevMouseState = false;
   break;
```

Right now it just glitches and... acts weird.. It is quite hard to explain, sometimes it'l select, others, it'l select the wrong area.
Any help is apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create the logic I wrote countless times before:

```
MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    end = new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);

    if (prevMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
    {
        start = end;
        selecting = true;
    }
}
else
    selecting = false;

prevMouseState = mouseState;
```

This is my update-logic for getting the two points (in my case two `Vector2` called `start` and `end`) and a variable that indicates if I am currently dragging around.

I tried to optimize it as best as I could:

I get a location on every update-call as long as I press Mouse1. When I press Mouse1 for the first time, I assign the newly generated location to the starting location and keep it (in your case a `Vector4`). `selecting` can be anything, from a boolean to an event that fires. It is just an example and can be extended.

I keep a reference to the last information I got from the mouse and update it at the bottom of my code.

It also prevents me from calling `Mouse.GetState()` more than once.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I had already fixed my code before you had posted, but mine is the equivalent of yours. I found that the error was mainly in the code which converts 2 vector2s to a rectangle. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45259788/8050514